# Jquery Json parse

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to parse json data using jquery parseJSON as following 
**JSON data :**

```
{
    "0": {
        "0": "Item 1",
        "1": "",
        "2": "",
        "3": "",
        "4": "",
        "5": "",
        "childs": {}
    },
    "1": {
        "0": "Item 2",
        "1": "",
        "2": "",
        "3": "",
        "4": "",
        "5": "",
        "childs": {
            "0": {
                "0": "Item 2 - Sub 1",
                "1": "",
                "2": "",
                "3": "",
                "4": "",
                "5": ""
            },
            "1": {
                "0": "Item 2 - Sub 2",
                "1": "",
                "2": "",
                "3": "",
                "4": "",
                "5": ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not familiar of json data structure, I didn't find any way to read values when indexed by numeral keys and I didn't know how to read childs sub values.

Comment: which value you want to get?

Comment: all items and sub items values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `parseJSON` method to parse the string into an object:

```
var o = $.parseJSON(s);
```

Then you can access the properties with numerical names using the bracket syntax. For example, getting the item named `"1"`, then the `childs` property from that, then the child named `"0"` and it's property named `"0"`:

```
var item = o["1"].childs["0"]["0"];
```

With your example data, the variable `item` now contains `"Item 2 - Sub 1"`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/s4HLs/

---

To loop through all items you can use the `each` method. Example:

```
$.each(o, function(i, v){
  console.log(v["0"]);
});
```

This would write this to the console:

```
Item 1
Item 2
```

To loop through subitems you would nest loops. Example:

```
$.each(o, function(i, v){
    console.log(v["0"]);
    $.each(v.childs, function(j, c){
        console.log(c["0"]);
    });
});
```

This would write this to the console:

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 2 - Sub 1
Item 2 - Sub 2
```

Note that there are no subitems for the first item, as that object is empty.